# Scrambling Social Security Number

Tags: security, encryption, hash

I'm working with a data set that deals with personal data (i.e. data that deals with people, not [necessarily] private data)... This data that changes over time, and the format is imposed by the client. I need something to use as a primary key, and unfortunately the only field that uniquely identifies a person and doesn't change unpredictably is SSN. The ID number (primary key) is going to be public facing, so I can't publish that, but I'm hoping to obscure it.

- The result must be numeric.
- The result may be up to 25 digits long.
- The result must be unique.
- The result should be as difficult as possible to reverse without a key, given the constraints above.

Is there a numeric cipher that would fit this?

Am I crazy for trying this?

Comment: Do you need it to be reversible? You could simply anonymize it by ordering randomly then assigning monotonically increasing integers, i.e., create a map between SSN and id, then replace all SSNs with the associated id and throw away the map.

Comment: Your size and numeric-only requirements make this tricky and rule out stronger candidates like SHA and even MD5.  I would probably go with a surrogate key that you assign, with SSN as just a piece of metadata (if you keep it at all.)

Comment: I'm not working with a fixed data set... people are added and removed continuously... so I'd have to randomize all 880000000 possible SSNs... possible, I guess, but the lookup would be a beast...

Comment: I can't assign the key myself... I'm tracking people over time based on the client's data, so I *have* to use SSN, or an analog of it.

Comment: You don't need to have every SSN stored. That is just a waste of time and resources. You just need to have a way to publicly map each SSN in your database to a unique number, which will be the primary key. Could you explain your situation and constraints a little more? I'm not quite sure what you can and can't work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Format perserving encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) sounds like a solution to your problems. Use this on the SSN and then  you just have some random 10 digit number that you can pad out to the 25 digit id you need. If you do the padding right, you can even invert it (if you have the key). The point is that after running it through the format perserving encryption, you data is not sensitive.

Comment: thanks! I was looking for an algorithm to obscure invoice number. And did not know what it is called.  The wiki link is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A social security number is nine digits long, which means there are only `10^9 = 1,000,000,000` unique SSNs. Most operations you perform on a SSN can be bruteforced, so I suggest you just assign unique random 25-digit numbers to each SSN. The random 25-digit number is your public ID, and the relationship between each pair is totally private.

The random key is not dependent upon the data it is assigned to, so there is no way to retrieve the input from the output (if you think of it as a function).

Comment: Excellent point - the ease of a dictionary attack makes any hashing solution a bad idea, unless computing the hash is quite expensive.

Comment: Thanks. Just out of curiosity, do you know of any cryptographically-secure hashing functions that can spit out integers?

Comment: Based on the way that I'm using the data, I have to use a hash. Essentially, the answer that I'm seeing is 'You're crazy for trying this'.

Comment: @Barton, not necessarily. You just need to keep a fixed mapping of SSN->KEY for the entire (1b) keyspace, at least at the point of importing new data.

Comment: @Barton This answer only proves that you need a **secret key** because a one-way function doesn't work due to the small number of plaintexts. In this case an 80 bit block cypher seems to be the right choice.

Comment: @Joe: SSNs  have the following constraints: The  first 3 digits may not be in the range of 900-999, nor equal to 000 or 666, so we can knock 112K out of the 10^9 set of possible SSNs. If I create a random number to map to each of the remaining numbers, I'm going to have about 3.2 GB of data to map to (assuming that I store the mappings as 4 byte integers). The box where I'm running the mapping has 2GB of ram, so I would have to do lookups off the hard drive... it's possible, I guess...

Comment: @Gumdrig *computing* the hash doesn't have to be expensive, *looking up* the hash should be. Essentially, what I'm looking for is an NP-Hard function uniquely mapping a 9 digit integer to a 25 digit integer. Anyone got one of those lying around?

Comment: @BartonChittenden: But you are assuming that you have data for *every single SSN*. That is twice the size of the number of people *with* SSNs. You should be computing the size of your table with regard to the number of unique SSNs you actually have.

Comment: @Blender -- hmm. I was thinking that figuring out whether a given key was unique would be an expensive operation (ergo, not something that I wanted to do on the fly), but I suppose that I could hash it. I'm leaning toward CodeInChaos's approach, simply because I don't have to worry about the SSN->ID table getting corrupted at some point in the future (this is going to be operating in the field, if the box crashes and has to be replaced, I don't want all previous data mappings to go with it)

Comment: Barton, *computing* the hash needs to be expensive to defeat a dictionary attack (i.e., to reverse the hash, hash every SSN until you get a match). But as @CodeInChaos sagely points out, if you can keep your hash function secret, that solves your problem.

Comment: @Blender, you can express any hash digest as an integer. E.g. an MD5 hash is usually expressed as hex digits, but 20 hexadecimal digits of it could be converted into (really, represented as) a 25-or-less-digit decimal number.

Comment: @Grumdig: Yeah, yesterday I made the connection between base-16, base conversion, and base-10. No idea why it didn't click.